# Распарсить JSON из переменной и взять первый элемент массива из поля используя Shell

Tags: linux, json, shell

**Дано:**

```
{"code":200,"lang":"ru-en","text":["test"]}
```

**Задача:**

Поместить `test` в переменную.

**Как пробую:**

```
text = '{"code":200,"lang":"ru-en","text":["test"]}'

translate = $($text | jq '.text[0]')

echo $translate
```

В итоге пишет, что `не найдено`.

**Вопрос:**

Почему требуется больше часа на вытаскивание значения из `JSON`?

Comment: translate=$(echo $text | jq '.text[0]')

Comment: @VladVetrov, это работает, спасибо) Но как я должен был понять, что `echo` нужно было? =( Я больше часа убил на гугленье и мат(

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Надо было читать внимательней сообщение об ошибке - `-bash: {"code":200,"lang":"ru-en","text":["test"]}: command not found` - до пайпа нужна выполняема команда, коей содержимое переменной text не является.

Comment: @0xdb, вроде понял... Просто мне выдавало такое: `16: /tmp/tomcat8-tomcat8-tmp/jenkins8610740465972801402.sh: {"code":200,"lang":"ru-en","text":["test"]}: not found` и я думал, что в `JSON` найти не может(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
text='{"code":200,"lang":"ru-en","text":["test"]}'
translate="$(echo "$text" | jq '.text[0]')"
echo "$translate"
```

Из важного:

- Одинарные кавычки в инициализации `text`
- `echo` и двойные кавычки в `translate`

А ещё на bash'е можно так сделать: `translate="$(jq '.text[0]' <<<"$text")"`

Comment: Спасибо) Я больше часа гугл ковырял но так и не нашёл нигде, что надо `echo` добавить( Что мне надо было знать/гуглить чтобы понять что его таки надо добавить?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, это базовые принципы работы с bash... изначальная строка имела смысл "выполнить команду сохранённую в $text и передать её вывод через трубу в jq", что в данном случае бессмысленно... Так что, вероятно, стоит для начала какой-нить букварь по bash почитать...

Comment: Понял, спасибо) Просто мне надо релиз ноты автоматом переводить для запихивания их при автоматической сборке андроид приложения и я не ожидал, что надо учебники читать для казалось бы простой операции)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, боюсь спросить, а вы и программы без использования учебников  пишете? Можно тогда узнать какие, чтобы не дай б-г не воспользоваться?

Comment: @0andriy, когда мне нужно написать программу, делающую запрос в сеть и пишущую результат в файл я не вижу смысла читать учебник. Зачем, если без чтения оного задача будет решена в разы быстрее? А вообще - это старый спор - как лучше учится - начиная с теории или с практики. Мне вот второй вариант ближе. Вам, видимо, первый. Программы могу показать. Вот, например: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.dante.scpfoundation

Comment: Программы не так показывают технарям, github url где?